# how to automate "amazon-add-to-cart" procedure using java selenium without opening the browser

Tags: selenium

I want to automate "amazon-add-to-cart" procedure.
the flow is to send http get method of the requested items, and then
submitting a button of the returning html.

the 1st url for example is:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AssociateTag=your-tag&ASIN.1=B003IXYJYO&Quantity.1=2&ASIN.2=B0002KR8J4&Quantity.2=1&ASIN.3=B0002ZP18E&Quantity.3=1&ASIN.4=B0002ZP3ZA&Quantity.4=2&ASIN.5=B004J2JG6O&Quantity.5=1%22

after that the user should click the continue button in order to indeed adding the items to the cart.

can you provide an example of how to code this flow with the button click using java selenium - without openning the browser?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the "HTMLUnitDriver" Webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("Enter the URL");
```